# Redirect one Apex Zone to another in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

According to AWS in the below article you can configure one apex zone to route to another apex zone using an alias record. When I attempt to do this it says my domain is invalid and the example text says it must be an RRS in the same hosted zone in order to specify a domain such as foo.com

This previous post lists the AWS doc as the solution to the problem however the doc does not explain how to actually configure the record and all attempts I've made have errored. How can I configure my domain bar.com to route to foo.com in Route 53?

AWS Doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingAliasRRSets.html

Previous Post: [RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name foo.com. is not permitted at apex in zone bar.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215729/rrset-of-type-cname-with-dns-name-foo-com-is-not-permitted-at-apex-in-zone-bar)

Answer (score 3):

What you are attempting is not possible.

From the page you cited:

> an alias resource record set contains a pointer to a CloudFront distribution, an Elastic Beanstalk environment, an ELB Classic, Application, or Network Load Balancer, an Amazon S3 bucket that is configured as a static website, or another Amazon Route 53 resource record set **in the same hosted zone.** *(emphasis added)*
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingAliasRRSets.html

Cross-hosted-zone records are only supported when the target is one of the AWS services listed here.  Otherwise, an alias can only point to a record in the same hosted zone.

Comment: Thanks Michael. In that case I will use a s3 bucket with a static website to facilitate the redirect.