# AWS Route53 Forward requests to Subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

**Setup**

I have a multi account setup in AWS.

**Account 1** is responsible for DNS hosting / resolution
**Account 2** hosts a development environment for a web app
**Account 3** hosts a production environment for the same web app

**Account 1**
Hosted Zone: `example.com`
Name Servers: `dev.example.com`
Name Servers: `prd.example.com`

**Account 2**
Hosted Zone: `dev.example.com`
A record (alias): `Load Balancer DNS Name`

**Account 3**
Hosted Zone: `prd.example.com`
A record (alias): `Load Balancer DNS Name`

This all works as expected, my subdomains resolve to the Load Balancers.

**Problem**

For the production account I want users to be able to type in `example.com` and have that resolve to the A record alias or `prd.example.com`.

I assumed I would be able to do this by adding a `CNAME` record in Account 1 with the production hosted zone name.  However I get the following error:

[image]

I've googled this error and found [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215729/rrset-of-type-cname-with-dns-name-foo-com-is-not-permitted-at-apex-in-zone-bar) answer.  It seems to suggest it's not possible (but this was back in 2013).

I know that DNS forwarding can be achieved using an S3 bucket, but that seems like such an ugly solution.  Is there another way I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: [Sean Faria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8916407) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66573246) saying "The answer is this create an s3 bucket redirect. See link https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/"

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct. A Canonical Name (CNAME) cannot exist, by definition, at the Apex (top level) in a zone as it has the potential to cause a conflict.

You can read an excellent FreeCodeCamp article on the subject [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-cant-a-domain-s-root-be-a-cname-8cbab38e5f5c/).