# AWS certificate renewal failed, problem trying to update CNAME records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I received an email from AWS:

> To renew this certificate, you must ensure that the proper CNAME
>   records are present in your DNS configuration for each domain listed
>   below

So I went to https://ap-northeast-2.console.aws.amazon.com/acm/ and grabbed the CNAME and tried to create a CNAME record in route-53

It fails with message

> [RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name example.kr. is not permitted at
>   apex in zone example.kr.]

I have a `A record` for `example.kr` which I created by following directions in `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html`

[RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name foo.com. is not permitted at apex in zone bar.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215729/rrset-of-type-cname-with-dns-name-foo-com-is-not-permitted-at-apex-in-zone-bar) says I'm getting the error message because I have `SOA` record for the domain, I have no idea why I have this record, and if I need it or not.

Can I simply delete `SOA` record and proceed or should I take different steps?

Comment: Hi, so what is your hosted zone in the case above? zone.bar.com or bar.com?

Comment: bar.com it is @mokugo-devops

Comment: Hi, could you possibly try to update your DNS names in the question to match. There seems to be 3 domains, example.kr, foo.com and zone.bar.com. If they're meant to be all part of the same domain please update it so that it is visible.

Comment: it's all same domain. example.kr (bar.com is in the title of another SO question)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the error you're seeing is because you're setting a `CNAME` on your root record (referred to as Apex record). This should be an A record (or Alias record in Route 53 when possible).

For [validating your certificate via CNAME](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-validate-dns.html) you will be given both a CNAME record and a value.

The CNAME record should start with an underscore followed by a large hash such as

`_a79865eb4cd1a6ab990a45779b4e0b96.yourdomain.com`.

If using Route 53 you should only need to enter `_a79865eb4cd1a6ab990a45779b4e0b96` as the domain name of type `CNAME`

You would then have a value similar to `_x2.acm-validations.aws.`. This would need to be your value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to [AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/acm/) and select list certificates, select the certificate in need of renewal. Under Domains click the button "Create records in Route 53". This takes you to a new page where you click "Create Records".

It typically takes DNS 30 minutes to propagate the record, and it might take several hours for Amazon to validate it and issue the certificate.

You can also check this [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easier-certificate-validation-using-dns-with-aws-certificate-manager/) for more info.