# AWS Route53 Error, trying to CNAME domain name to loadbalancer dns

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

**Situation:**

1. I have one loadbalancer which is serving a kubernetes cluster, and it has a dns name
2. I have my website domain, registered in route53 zone, and want to CNAME this to the dns of the loadbalancer

The initial records of the zone right after creation are:
[image]
Then I try to add the CNAME record of pointing `mydomain.com` to the loadbalancer DNS, and get the error shown in image:
[image]

**My question is now:**

How can I use mydomain.com to access the loadbalancer ? and still manage the dns records with route53 (i have other records for cdn etc in real domain aside root one that want to use for the loadbalancer serving the website)

Comment: I think it should be A record, and try to use Alias

Comment: I answered myself after finding out aliases, yes it needs to be alias. Just A record will not be correct solution because the loa balancer have multiple ips that change. By the way why is this not allowed ? If I buy a domain and host it let say in godaddy, how can i point it to load balancer without using route53 aliases

Comment: ELB has its own DNS, you can use it

Comment: @AshBlake I was using that, my question was something different that I could not assign CNAME to that dns. And no one wants to use directly DNS of LB, clients to come at 2938893893283298.aws.com lol, therefore wanted to point domain like mydomain.com cname to the dns of lb. But now solved with aliases as answered the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215729/rrset-of-type-cname-with-dns-name-foo-com-is-not-permitted-at-apex-in-zone-bar

Have you read this link yet? It said something like you can use CNAME record while having other records for that DNS at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for link, I checked now and do not see they mentioning that can use CNAME with other dns records at same time. The solutions I read there is same with aws aliases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that for this AWS specific solution, can use ALIASES instead of CNAME records to point the domain to a particular AWS Resource (loadbalancer in my case).
Aliases are DNS extensions for AWS system only

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html

Still this is very interesting question, and assuming no alias was possible, does it mean that you never can CNAME your bought root domain to some other domain ?